# How can I store any output from node program to a specific file?

Tags: shell, node.js, logging

I am running my node program like this

```
sudo NODE_ENV=production node app.js&
```

Apparently, everything works fine and it works even if the terminal is closed. If terminal that run the program is opened, output will be shown on the terminal.

It occasionally output some data, however, I cannot see it if original terminal was not opened, and unless I wait for the output 24 hours full time.

How can I redirect every string output from the program to specific file? so that I will be able to find out the possible cause of exception or unexpected termination of a node program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just tack on `>> file`

```
sudo NODE_ENV=production node app.js >> log.txt &
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nohup node app.js > app_logs.out
```

You can also use `NODE_ENV=production` in the example above if you want. [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) refers to 'no hangup'.

Resources:

[Node.js as a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service) 
[sudo nohup nice <-- in what order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350381/sudo-nohup-nice-in-what-order)

Answer (score 0):

use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)
for example -

```
forever start -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log my-daemon.js
```

where

`-l  LOGFILE      Logs the forever output to LOGFILE
 -o  OUTFILE      Logs stdout from child script to OUTFILE
 -e  ERRFILE      Logs stderr from child script to ERRFILE`

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) you can find all the documentation needed.

Comment: Your answer would look better, if you at least explained meanings of parameters